# Clickable jQuery tablesorter

Tags: jquery, onclick, tablesorter

I`m nooby in JS and jQuery and my question might be stupid. I am using jQuery tablesorter in my project and I am trying to make the table rows to be editable, so that when you click on a row, to be able to get the selected row id. For example, I have such table:

```
No | Name | Address
1  | Jon  | USA 
2  | Michael  | USA
```

So when I click on the second row, I want to get the No value. Any information sources for such implementation abour jQuery tablesorter will be usefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to make any changes to the HTML.

This method uses [delegated event binding](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events), so even if you add or remove any table rows, it'll still work - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/856bzzeL/111/)

```
$(function () {

    $('table')
        .on('click', 'tbody tr', function(){
            // closest finds the row, .eq(0) finds the first cell
            var id = $(this).closest('tr').children().eq(0).text();
            alert( id );
        })
        .tablesorter({
            theme: 'blue'
        });

});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your HTML, but let's say you have something like:

```
<table id="mytable">
<tr>
    <th>
        No
    </th>
     <th>
        Name
    </th> 
      <th>
        Address
    </th>
</tr>
<tr data-id="1">
    <td>
       1
    </td>
    <td>
        Jon
    </td>
    <td>
        USA
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

You could use:

```
$("#mytable tr")
    .on( "click", function(){
         var myId = $( this ).attr( "data-id" );
         // do something
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use everything that you use in normal DOM.

I have created a test fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/picklespy/oz31pj0n/

**HTML**

Assign a `class` to the rows and a class to the `No` columns. When someone clicks on the row, this example will alert the value in `No` column.

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="tablesorter">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th class="header headerSortDown">Name</th>
                <th class="header">Address</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="row">
                <td class="id">1</td>
                <td>Jon</td>
                <td>USA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="row">
                <td class="id">2</td>
                <td>Michael</td>
                <td>USA</td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tr.row').click(function() {
        alert($(this).find('td.id').text())
    });
});
```